# Turn off listener logging in oracle 12c release 2

Tags: oracle-12c, listener, sap

I am trying to turn off listener logging in oracle 12c R2 (SAP on oracle), but I am getting a TNS-12508 error. I have verified that the listener.ora is owned by the oracle user and I am performing the task as same oracle user, but I am still getting an error.

#### File Permissions

```
-rw-r--r--    1 oracle   oinstall       1151 Oct 23 13:48 listener.ora
```

#### Listener Error

```
LSNRCTL> set current_listener LISTENER_AAA.
Current Listener is LISTENER_AAA

LSNRCTL> set LOG_STATUS OFF
Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=AAA.WORLD))
TNS-12508: TNS:listener could not resolve the COMMAND given

LSNRCTL> set log_status off
Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=AAA.WORLD))
TNS-12508: TNS:listener could not resolve the COMMAND given
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: can you check the version of the listener by using the VERSION command?

Comment: check for parameter in  listner.ora if  ADMIN_RESTRICTIONS_LISTENER was set to ON?

Comment: Sam is correct here. This is caused by `ADMIN_RESTRICTIONS_LISTENER_AAA` set to on.

Comment: Thanks sam, i cross checked the listener file ADMIN_RESTRICTIONS_LISTENER was ON.Turning it off resolved the issue.

Comment: @Sam Could you pop your solution into an answer? It provides an answer to the question and we could clean up things here in the comments. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This can happen if you've got `ADMIN_RESTRICTIONS_LISTENER` set to `ON` in your `listener.ora` file.

Turning it off should resolve the problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/123599)

Comment: Looks like RDFozz fixed the answer.Thanks RDFOzz